# Could not stop in a timely manner

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am having a windows service which I am planning to do an auto restart through windows batch file using "net stop" command. Sometime the service may stop abruptly and show a message box "Could not stop windows service".

Please advise me if i stop the service from windows batch file using "net stop" command whether the popup message will show if the command is unable is stop the service. Kindly assist.

Comment: `net stop` is a console application and will never show a message box.  (Unless it crashes I suppose, but that's very unlikely.)

Answer (score 0):

Net Stop is synchronous, meaning it will wait until the service is stopped.

So you are planning to restart the service just do

```
net stop servicename && net start servicename
```

`net stop` will wait until the service is stopped and then run `net start`

Additionally, using the `&&` method, we reply on the first command to be successful then run the second, if the first command fails, it will not run the second command.

If you have a very stubborn service which is not able to stop, you can build in a loop to check if it is running by using `tasklist` then attempt to restart if `%ERRORLEVEL%` is not 0.

You can also see how long the timeout is for the Service Kill in regedit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WaitToKi‌​llServiceTimeout
```

Mine for instance in windows 8 is set to `5000 seconds`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. net stop will wait until the service is stopped...Does that mean it will continously wait until the service enters stopped state or whether it will wait for somed duration. Below is what I am planning to do

Comment: It waits for a duration, but by default on my Windows 8 Device, the timeout is 5000 seconds. If you have a service that takes longer than 83 minutes, then you have a problem. You could also look at using tasklist and taskkill if it takes longer than N amount of time.